# Turn an array of pairs of start and end points into an ordered series

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array, graph

Given an array of pairs, for example:

[["Denver", "Miami"], ["Miami", "Tulsa"], ["LA", "Okmulgee"], ["Mobile", "Portland"], ["Tucson", "LA"]]

What's the best way to arrange these pairs into an array of arrays that looks like:

[["Denver", "Miami", "Tulsa"], ["Tucson", "LA", "Okmulgee"], ["Mobile", "Portland"]]

Where arrays with duplicate cities are matched and consolidated, and the order of the other cities in the array is preserved in the new array. If the cities in a pair don't match any other cities of any other pair, then that pair remains unchanged.

Cities will **not** loop back into each other. However, there can be branching, for instance [["Miami", "Tulsa"], ["Tulsa", "Park City"], ["Tulsa", "Anniston"]]

Below is a solution that a friend helped me with that seems to work pretty well, but I was wondering if anyone could come up with something more intuitive, cleaner, or just generally better.

Someone smarter than me has suggested that this problem may be solved with/by [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). I would need some hand-holding for that, I'm afraid.

```
let connectedPairs = [["Denver", "Miami"], ["Miami", "Tulsa"], ["LA", "Okmulgee"], ["Mobile", "Portland"], ["Tucson", "LA"]] // example array of pairs
let ordered = [[...connectedPairs[0]]]
for (let i = 1; i < connectedPairs.length; i++) {
  const start = connectedPairs[i][0];
  const end = connectedPairs[i][1];
  let matched = false;

  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < ordered.length; i2++) {
    if (
        ordered[i2].includes(end) === true &&
        ordered[i2].includes(start) === false
    ) {
        matched = true;
        const index = ordered[i2].findIndex((id) => end === id);
        ordered[i2].splice(index, 0, start);
    } else if (
        ordered[i2].includes(start) === true &&
        ordered[i2].includes(end) === false
    ) {
      matched = true
        ordered[i2].push(end);
    }
  }
    if (!matched) {
       if (connectedPairs[i].length > 2 && connectedPairs[i][2] === 2) {
          connectedPairs[i].pop(); // takes 2 off
          ordered.push([...connectedPairs[i]]);
       } else if (connectedPairs[i].length > 2 && connectedPairs[i][2] === 1){
          connectedPairs.push([start, end, 2]);
       } else if (connectedPairs[i].length === 2) {
          connectedPairs.push([start, end, 1]);
       }
    }
}

console.log(ordered)
```

*Output:  [["Denver", "Miami", "Tulsa"], ["Tucson", "LA", "Okmulgee"], ["Mobile", "Portland"]]*

Comment: While I don't think I'll have much to contribute algorithm-wise, I wanted to point out you're not clear enough on what you want. Are you assuming no branching and no loops? are the connections directional? (Examples: what if you also had ["Tulsa", "Denver"]? that's a loop. how about ["Denver", "Chicago"]? that's a branch). Also, if the tag exist, consider adding `graph` tag

Comment: @user1999728 Thank you for the input. There won't be any loops, but there can be branching. I will update the post.

Comment: You're welcome. I had another thought regarding making the code more readable (the reason I'm not just answering your question is that I know very little Javascript and graph theory): Consider using maps. place all connections in a `Map` (big M), then take the `keys()`, and use `keys.map((element) => Map[element])`. This can replace one loop, though restrictions (exceptions if the element isn't in the map, for example) may apply. Good luck!

Comment: I've heard of map, but not Map. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please describe what the expected output should be for the `[["Miami", "Tulsa"], ["Tulsa", "Park City"], ["Tulsa", "Anniston"]]` branching case?

Comment: To shallow clone an array, consider using `[...a]` rather than `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))`

Comment: @Wyck yes. The expected output there could be [["Miami", "Tulsa", "Park City", "Anniston"]] or [["Miami", "Tulsa", "Anniston", "Park City"]]. Either one would work.
Good call on the [...a]

Comment: @Wyck the spread operator looks good. I will update the post to use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is a breadth-first traversal of a tree.  Asserting the prior that there are no cycles or merging branches (nodes with multiple parents), it can be done like this by repeatedly making a list of the next values to be visited in the traversal.

```js
function breadthFirstTraversal(pairs) {
  const rhs = new Set(pairs.map(p => p[1]));
  const lhs = [...new Set(pairs.map(p => p[0]).filter(v => !rhs.has(v)))];
  return lhs.map(v => {
    const result = [v];
    let next = result;
    while (next.length)
      result.push(...(next = pairs.filter(p => next.includes(p[0])).map(p => p[1])));
    return result;
  });
}

const connectedPairs1 = [["Denver", "Miami"], ["Miami", "Tulsa"], ["LA", "Okmulgee"], ["Mobile", "Portland"], ["Tucson", "LA"]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(breadthFirstTraversal(connectedPairs1)));

const connectedPairs2 = [["Miami", "Tulsa"], ["Tulsa", "Park City"], ["Tulsa", "Anniston"]];
console.log(JSON.stringify(breadthFirstTraversal(connectedPairs2)));
```

Comment: This is awesome and works like a charm. I would upvote, but I am not reputable enough. I will go over this until I understand everything you've done. Thanks again.

Comment: There may be a problem, given data `[["A", "B"], ["D", "E"], ["A", "C"],["D", "F"],["C","F"]]` your function returns `[["A","B","C","F"],["D","E","F"]]` (note `"F"` in both arrays) rather than expected  `["A","B","C","D","E","F"]`

Comment: @Blindman67 See where I wrote: _Asserting the prior that there are no cycles or merging branches_

Comment: The example I gave has no cycles. It is completely unclear what *"merging branches"* means. The OP's code is pruning. The OP's code will *`merge????`* `["A", "B", "C"],  ["D", "E", "F"]` when encountering `["A","D"]`, if given the input `[["A", "B"], ["A", "C"],  ["D", "E"],  ["D", "F"], ["A","D"]]`.  The expected result I gave in the comment is taken from the OP's result for that input.

Comment: I'm sorry for using unclear terminology.  By _merging_ I meant that a child has only one parent.  Or that a symbol will only appear on the right hand side of at most one pair.  So having both pairs ["D", "F"] and ["C", "F"] would violate this one-parent assertion.  If  multiple parents are allowed, then we are indeed back to topological sorting (which has already been linked to).  None of the examples in the original question contained nodes with multiple parents, so I offered a solution that can work if nodes with multiple parents are known not to exist. I will edit to clarify.